# How do I get the current image of an animated GIF image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif) framework to animate a GIF I made, problem is I need to know which image is currently displaying.
The extension is using `UIImage.animatedImage(with images: [UIImage], duration: TimeInterval) -> UIImage?` to display the animated image.

Here is how I load my gif :

```
spikes.loadGif(name: "Trap")
```

and here is how I get the image I'd like to compare it to :

```
spikes.image.images[2]
```

I know those are weak explanations but I can't find any more relevant informations, however I can give you more informations if it can help you.

If you know any other solution that could involve me using another framework I would take it too.

Comment: Possibly not possible. Support for static GIF in iOS is not exactly *native*, thus the need for third party frameworks. Have you contacted the developer of this? Do you have access to the source code?

Comment: Yes you also can access the source code by clicking the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ever needs an answer as I did, I found a way to do it.

1. Load GIF with the extension's loadGif() method
2. Since the images that are composing the GIF are now stored in `spikes.image.images`, I store those images in another var
3. Set `spikes.image = nil` to cancel animations generated from `loadGif()` method
4. Make a timer that keeps changing the actual image of the view

Here's how it looks like :

```
spikes.loadGif(name: "Trap", completion: { _ in
            self.spikesImages = self.spikes.image?.images
            self.spikes.image = nil
            self.spikes.image = self.spikesImages.first?.img
            self.animateSpikes()
        })

func animateSpikes() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            if let currentImage = self.spikesImages.first {
                self.spikes.image = currentImage
                self.spikesImages.append(currentImage)
                self.spikesImages.remove(at: 0)
            }
        })
    }
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to do it but it works